# Сортировка файла

Tags: алгоритм

Есть задача: отсортировать массив `4-х значных` чисел, записанных в файл. При этом нельзя сделать его (файла) копию или (полностью) выгружать его в оперативку. Само задание я реализовал, но через пузырьковую сортировку - что мне не очень нравится, так как это довольно примитивно, но, при этом, я не нашел более приемлимого алгоритма для этой задачи... Рассматривал сортировку вставками, но мне она кажется не эффективной в этих условиях, так как постоянно нужно прыгать по файлу (ИМХО, это будет даже дольше чем пузырьковая, так как во второй каждый цикл начинается с постоянной и известной позиции (начала файла) - что, я думаю, преимущество.

Какой алгоритм сдесь будет эффективнее, чем упомянутая пузырьковая?

Comment: Ага, т.е. пишем в тот же файл. но можно работать только с отдельными ... числами или блоками ? я ведь могу по условиям считать половину файла отсортировать и записать ее обратно. хотя я подозреваю, что в условиях надо просто сказать "читать и записывать файл можно только отдельными числами". Вообще qsort считается более эффективным чем пузырьковая. почему бы его не применить к файлу

Comment: @Mike Не важно отдельными числами или целыми блоками - просто представьте, что файл настолько огромен (ну или оперативка так мала), что он полностью не поместится в оперативку. Что касается qsort - подскажите как в файле реализовать рекурсию? Вот этого я точно не представляю.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, когда компьютеры были большими, а оперативной памяти было мало, использовали [внешнюю сортировку](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Внешняя_сортировка). Сейчас для сортировки больших файлов тоже актуально.

Comment: "_Не важно отдельными числами или целыми блоками_". А вот это как раз крайне важно. Потому что можно загрузить блок, отсортировать его, записать, отсортировать следующий. А потом использовать сортировку слиянием нескольких блоков, например. Мне тут недавно надо было быстро отсортировать 150 млн записей. Объем данных 100Гб. В общем я его прочитал, сразу примерно по значению ключа разбил на 150 разных файлов, после чего отсортировал каждый файл в отдельности и при последоветльном чтении этих файлов получил записи в нужном порядке

Comment: Ну и с рекурсией проблем не вижу. Условия запрещают хранить файл в ОЗУ. А в стеке при рекурсии храниться фактически только разбивка на части, а не сами данные

Comment: @Mike условие смотрите, пожалуйста: все должно быть в одном файле

Comment: @insolor проблема в слиянии - не думаю, что его можно организовать не прибегая к созданию дополнительных файлов

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Я просто привел пример. В вашем случае можно без файлов обойтись. Разбиваем файл на блоки. Каждый блок по отдельности загружаем в ОЗУ, сортируем чем душе угодно, пишем на место. После чего организуем отдельный курсор для чтения каждого блока и делаем сортировку слиянием, вычитывая из файла небольшими фрагментами от каждого блока согласно текущему курсору в нем

Comment: А еще, учитывая что у нас только 4х значные числа, а их не много, можно предположить (или на первом проходе по файлу оценить) каково может быть распределение. Зная распределение и количество значений (объем файла) по любому значению можно вычислить его примерное положение в отсортированном файле. Тогда мы берем первое значение, вычисляем где оно примерно будет, пишем его в эту точку, предварительно забрав то, что лежит сейчас там. Повторяем в цикле для сохраненного из точки вставки числа. Потом досортировываем отдельные блоки

Comment: @Mike имеете ввиду сортировку подсчетом?

Comment: Ну судя по описанию в википедии сортировка подсчетом это нечто иное. я написал предложение в расчете на то, что как раз повторяющихся значений не очень много. Я лишь предложил для начала перенести значения примерно в те регионы файла, где они предположительно должны находиться. Если построить предварительно индекс скажем по первым двум числам, посчитав кол-во значений которые на него начинаются, то можно достаточно точно представлять где что должно находиться

Comment: @Mike странное предположение, учитывая, что четырехзначныч чисело всего 9000...

Comment: А вы в задаче про это почему то не написали. Может у вас оперативной памяти 1 килобайт. А между тем статистика распределения - это ключевое звено в выборе правильного алгоритма

Comment: Но если их даже много одинаковых - это особо ничего не меняет. может конечно привести к распределению далекому от нормального, что затруднит прямой перевод значение->координата. но с индексом по количеству сотен должно быть вполне переводимо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ключевой момент здесь - `4-х значных чисел`, т.е. диапазон данных очень узок, и элементы не имеют вторичных полей.

В данном случае достаточно создать массив 64-битных счётчиков длиной 10000, пройтись по файлу, инкрементируя соответствующий счётчик, а потом записать в тот же файл каждый элемент столько раз, сколько содержится в его счётчике. Получается [CountingSort](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%87%D1%91%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC)